# STSAdm Access Denied and UAC

Tags: stsadm

If you have an access denied error message when executing an STSAdm command its easy to solve by turning off UAC.

I can understand this, but what I would like to know is, what is the offical way to solve the access denied message while keeping UAC turned on.

Reason is: In some environments, some NA's get really annoyed if you disable UAC or adjust this setting. I personally see UAC as a hindrance, but there are certain times when disabling it is against company regulations.

You might say - just disable it - run the command then re-enable it. Yes you can do this, but this also requires 2 system restarts. Clearly not always an option if you're working on a busy production site without load balancing.

Is there any official Microsoft documentation on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure but you could always just pop open a command line "As Administrator" - you only get the UAC pop up once that way.

Comment: Seems like a good solution - run the stsadm command as administrator and bypass UAC once for that call... thanks!

Comment: if you hold down SHIFT while right-clicking console (or PowerShell, IE or other) you get both the As Administrator and As Another User in context menu. Very useful when you want to connect with another user :-)